# Change text to what the variable is. Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make the text change to the amount of grenades the player has left. I have tried to set the amount of grenades 3 and then on start to show whatever the amount of grenades is for the text to be that too. But i get these error:

Assets\Scripts\ThrowGrenade.cs(20,24): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'

and

Assets\Scripts\ThrowGrenade.cs(23,10): error CS1624: The body of 'ThrowGrenade.Update()' cannot be an iterator block because 'void' is not an iterator interface type

This is my code:

```
    public int amountOfGrenades = 3;
    public GameObject grenadesText;
    public GameObject NOgrenadesText;


    void Start()
    {
        
        grenadesText = amountOfGrenades;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("q") && amountOfGrenades >= 1)
        {
            ThrowingGrenade();
        }

        if(amountOfGrenades == 0)
        {

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);
            NOgrenadesText.SetActive(true); // Enable the text so it shows
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);
            NOgrenadesText.SetActive(false); // Disable the text so it is hidden
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The first error is pretty self explanatory.

   You probably mean

   ```
   grenadesText.GetComponent<Text>().text = amountOfGrenades.ToString();
   ```

   .. or directly make it

   ```
   public Text grenadesText;
   ```

   Or whatever text component you are using (e.g. `TMP_Text`)
2. And then you can't use `yield` within the `Update` method ... Only within `IEnumerator` methods ...

Should probably look somewhat like

```
public int amountOfGrenades = 3;
// Simply use the correct type right away
public Text grenadesText;
public GameObject NOgrenadesText;

private void Start()
{     
    grenadesText.text =  amountOfGrenades.ToString();
}

private void Update()
{
    // Avoid the stringed versions wherever possible
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
    {
        if(amountOfGrenades > 0)
        {
            // I don't know what happens in here
            // but whenever you are increasing or decreasing the amountOfGranades value
            // you again want to call
            // grenadesText.text =  amountOfGrenades.ToString();
            // in order to update the display
            ThrowingGrenade();
        }

        if(amountOfGrenades == 0)
        {
            StopAllCoroutines ();
            StartCoroutine (NoGrenadesRoutine());
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerator NoGrenadesRoutine ()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);
    NOgrenadesText.SetActive(true); // Enable the text so it shows
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);
    NOgrenadesText.SetActive(false); // Disable the text so it is hidden
}
```

Comment: Try again please ;) I fixed it in the first snippet but not in the complete code .. only on the smartphone so a bit of patience ;)

Comment: I am unable to put my grenadesText into the inspector

Comment: What is its type? What component are you using?

Comment: I changed it back to GameObject instead of Text and it works. The code itself though it not doing what its supposed to

Comment: Please respond to the question ;) what type are you using? And I just updated the code .. as said a little patience please .. if you change it back to GameObject .. you still need to use GetComponent in order to get the correct component from that object .. so rather use the correct component type right away

Comment: I did, I said I had it as public Text grenadesText; and I changed it to public GameObject grenadesText; This works now. I also have  grenadesText.GetComponent<Text>().text = amountOfGrenades.ToString(); in my void start()

Comment: I don't see why `public Text grenadesText;` should not work .. are you sure it is using `UnityEngine.UI.Text` and not maybe some different type with equal name?

Answer (score 0):

try using `grenadesText.text = numberOfGrenades.ToString()`; or using `grenadesText.test = numberOfGrenades+""// empty string, can also use String.Empty`; the first uses object's toString method, latter adds and empty string.

Answer (score -1):

Okay. First of all, you are not referencing the actual text field, you are just referencing the GameObject. To reference the text field you must do this:

First use the correct library

```
using UnityEngine.UI;  //To use the UI library
```

or

```
using TMPro; //If using Text Mesh Pro
```

Then use the correct variable:

```
public Text grenadesText; //This is the correct way to use the Text object, it comes with its own properties and methods.
```

or

```
public TMP_Text grenadesText; //If using Text Mesh Pro
```

Now that we have our variables and libraries correctly used, we can start coding. It's really simple. Just do this:

```
    void Start()
    {
        
        grenadesText.text = amountOfGrenades;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("q") && amountOfGrenades >= 1)
        {
            ThrowingGrenade();
        }

        if(amountOfGrenades == 0)
        {

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);
            NOgrenadesText.SetActive(true); // Enable the text so it shows
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);
            NOgrenadesText.SetActive(false); // Disable the text so it is hidden
        }
    }
```

Hope it helped

Comment: I've got using UnityEngine.UI; I just haven't included it in the code snippet here. I still get the same error with that code: Assets\Scripts\ThrowGrenade.cs(20,29): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Comment: Try using:  grenadesText.text = numberOfGrenades.ToString();